# String and hexadecimal representation

Tags: python, string, hex

I'm trying the following:

```
>>> a = '\01'
>>> a
>>> '\x01'
>>> b = '\11'
>>> b
>>> '\t'
>>> c = '\21'
>>> c
>>> '\x11'
```

I don't understand why sometimes I get hexadecimal representation and other times not.

 In '\xhh' the 'x' is fundamental or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The numbers \11, \21 are OCTAL numbers.  \11 octal is \x09 (hex) is equal to '\t' (tab char). \21 octal is \x11 hex is 17 decimal.

Comment: thanls. in the doc where is written that '\11' is interpreted as an octal number?

Comment: For instance here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h21280bw.aspx but I guess it must be in some official ANSI C reference document as well.

Answer (score 5):

### Short Answer

You see the hexadecimal representation for those characters for which your native code page cannot represent your characters

### Long Answer

Assuming you are using windows, and your default code page is `cp1252`, `'\01'` is a non-printable character, an ascii control code, which stands for `Start of Heading`. As there is no known printable representation of the character, a hexadecimal value is used to display the value.

Comment: I'm using linux. Sorry, I don't get. When I write `b='\21'` is it equivalent to `b='\x21'`?

Comment: @antox: They are equivalent as one is on octal and the other in hexadecimal.

Comment: "`'\01'` is a non-printable character, an ascii control code, which stands for `ASCII control code`" - what the heck are you trying to say? `\01` is "Start of Heading". It used to mark the start of a metadata section in a data stream.

Comment: @user2357112: Aha slip of finger. I actually wanted to say "Start of Heading"